# Bootstrap responsive column reset div vs JavaScript equal height script

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

just wanted you ask your opinions on which solution you'd go for regarding bootstrap Responsive column reset.
Option 1 - use bootstraps awsome `<div class="clearfix visible-xs-block"></div>`

Pros:

1) html & CSS only

2) uses built in media queries i.e inherantly responsive
   based on resizing of the viewport

Cons:

1) can lead to excessive markup based on how many media queries you have    for example

```
<div class="col-3-lg col-4-sm col-6-xs">module 1</div>
<div class="col-3-lg col-4-sm col-6-xs">module 2</div>
<div class="clearfix visible-xs-block"></div>
<div class="col-3-lg col-4-sm col-6-xs">module 2</div>
<div class="clearfix visible-sm-block"></div>
<div class="col-3-lg col-4-sm col-6-xs">module 2</div>
<div class="clearfix visible-lg-block"></div>
```

Option 2 - use javascript to make each block the same height thus preventing the problem from occuring.

Pros:
1) no additional html divs in code

Cons:
1) the only way this solution becomes responsive is to get the JS to check for window resize and apply the equal heights again

I'm sure there are a lot more pros and cons for each.

I'm really on the fence with which to use.

Apart from asking your opinions on which you prefer I guess one question is: in the option 1 scenario, is there a downside to having the additional clearfix divs?

EDIT
with the suggested use of flexbox I get equal height divs that work in firefox (PC & MAC) but not safari (on mac or ipad/iphone)
my implementation is as follows

```
        <fieldset id="tab-vehicle" class="tab-pane active" style="display:flex; flex-wrap:wrap;">
        <?PHP
        //$i=1;
        foreach ($this->vehicles as $vehicle){
        ?>
            <div class="v-details col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 vehicle<?PHP echo $vehicle->id; ?>">
                <div>
                    <div class="vc-image "><img src="<?PHP echo $vehicle->image; ?>" alt="pegasus samos rent-a-car <?PHP echo $vehicle->make; ?> <?PHP echo $vehicle->model; ?>" /></div>
                    <div class="vc-make-model"><?PHP echo $vehicle->make; ?> <?PHP echo $vehicle->model; ?></div>
                    <div class="vc-engine"><?PHP echo $vehicle->engine; ?></div>
                    <div class="vc-features"><?PHP  echo $vehicle->features; ?></div>
                <a href="#tab-booking" class="btn btn-warning selected" data-vehicle="<?PHP echo $vehicle->id; ?>">I'll have this one</a>
                 </div>
           </div>
        <?PHP
        //if ($i % 2 == 0) echo '<div class="clearfix visible-xs-block"></div>';
        //if ($i % 3 == 0) echo '<div class="clearfix visible-sm-block"></div>';
        //if ($i % 3 == 0) echo '<div class="clearfix visible-md-block"></div>';
        //if ($i % 4 == 0) echo '<div class="clearfix visible-lg-block"></div>';
        //$i++;
        };
        ?>


        </fieldset>
```

The code generated from the above PHP is as follows

```
<fieldset style="display: -webkit-flex; display: flex; -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap; flex-wrap: wrap;" class="tab-pane active" id="tab-vehicle">
                        <div class="v-details col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 vehicle1">
                <div>
                    <div class="vc-image "><img alt="pegasus samos rent-a-car Kia Picanto" src="/images/vehicles/picanto.jpg"></div>
                    <div class="vc-make-model">Kia Picanto</div>
                    <div class="vc-engine">1000cc</div>
                    <div class="vc-features"><ul class="tabs list-inline"><li class="label label-info">4 Doors</li><li class="label label-info"> 5 Seats</li><li class="label label-info"> Air Con</li></ul></div>
                <a data-vehicle="1" class="btn btn-warning selected" href="#tab-booking">I'll have this one</a>
                 </div>
           </div>
                        <div class="v-details col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 vehicle6 active">
                <div>
                    <div class="vc-image "><img alt="pegasus samos rent-a-car Hyundai Atos" src="/images/vehicles/atos.jpg"></div>
                    <div class="vc-make-model">Hyundai Atos</div>
                    <div class="vc-engine">1100cc</div>
                    <div class="vc-features"><ul class="tabs list-inline"><li class="label label-info">4 Doors</li><li class="label label-info"> 5 Seats</li><li class="label label-info"> Air Con</li></ul></div>
                <a data-vehicle="6" class="btn btn-warning selected" href="#tab-booking">I'll have this one</a>
                 </div>
           </div>
                        <div class="v-details col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 vehicle4">
                <div>
                    <div class="vc-image "><img alt="pegasus samos rent-a-car Suzuki Splash" src="/images/vehicles/suzuki_splash.jpg"></div>
                    <div class="vc-make-model">Suzuki Splash</div>
                    <div class="vc-engine">1300cc</div>
                    <div class="vc-features"><ul class="tabs list-inline"><li class="label label-info">5 Doors</li><li class="label label-info"> 5 Seats</li><li class="label label-info"> Air Con</li></ul></div>
                <a data-vehicle="4" class="btn btn-warning selected" href="#tab-booking">I'll have this one</a>
                 </div>
           </div>
                        <div class="v-details col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 vehicle7">
                <div>
                    <div class="vc-image "><img alt="pegasus samos rent-a-car Hyundai i10" src="/images/vehicles/hyundai_i10.jpg"></div>
                    <div class="vc-make-model">Hyundai i10</div>
                    <div class="vc-engine">1200cc</div>
                    <div class="vc-features"><ul class="tabs list-inline"><li class="label label-info">5 Doors</li><li class="label label-info"> 5 Seats</li><li class="label label-info"> Air Con</li></ul></div>
                <a data-vehicle="7" class="btn btn-warning selected" href="#tab-booking">I'll have this one</a>
                 </div>
           </div>
                        <div class="v-details col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 vehicle8">
                <div>
                    <div class="vc-image "><img alt="pegasus samos rent-a-car Hyundai i20" src="/images/vehicles/hyundai_i20.jpg"></div>
                    <div class="vc-make-model">Hyundai i20</div>
                    <div class="vc-engine">1200cc</div>
                    <div class="vc-features"><ul class="tabs list-inline"><li class="label label-info">5 Doors</li><li class="label label-info"> 5 Seats</li><li class="label label-info"> Air Con</li></ul></div>
                <a data-vehicle="8" class="btn btn-warning selected" href="#tab-booking">I'll have this one</a>
                 </div>
           </div>
                        <div class="v-details col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 vehicle9">
                <div>
                    <div class="vc-image "><img alt="pegasus samos rent-a-car Hyundai i30" src="/images/vehicles/hyundai_i30.jpg"></div>
                    <div class="vc-make-model">Hyundai i30</div>
                    <div class="vc-engine">1400</div>
                    <div class="vc-features"><ul class="tabs list-inline"><li class="label label-info">5 Doors</li><li class="label label-info"> 5 Seats</li><li class="label label-info"> Air Con</li></ul></div>
                <a data-vehicle="9" class="btn btn-warning selected" href="#tab-booking">I'll have this one</a>
                 </div>
           </div>
                        <div class="v-details col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 vehicle12">
                <div>
                    <div class="vc-image "><img alt="pegasus samos rent-a-car Kia Rio" src="/images/vehicles/kia-rio.jpg"></div>
                    <div class="vc-make-model">Kia Rio</div>
                    <div class="vc-engine">1300cc</div>
                    <div class="vc-features"><ul class="tabs list-inline"><li class="label label-info">4 Doors</li><li class="label label-info"> 5 Seats</li><li class="label label-info"> Air Con</li></ul></div>
                <a data-vehicle="12" class="btn btn-warning selected" href="#tab-booking">I'll have this one</a>
                 </div>
           </div>
                        <div class="v-details col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 vehicle10">
                <div>
                    <div class="vc-image "><img alt="pegasus samos rent-a-car Suzuki Samurai" src="/images/vehicles/samurai.jpg"></div>
                    <div class="vc-make-model">Suzuki Samurai</div>
                    <div class="vc-engine">1300cc</div>
                    <div class="vc-features"><ul class="tabs list-inline"><li class="label label-info">2 Doors</li><li class="label label-info"> 4 Seats</li><li class="label label-info"> Cabriolet</li><li class="label label-info"> Air Con</li></ul></div>
                <a data-vehicle="10" class="btn btn-warning selected" href="#tab-booking">I'll have this one</a>
                 </div>
           </div>
                        <div class="v-details col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 vehicle15">
                <div>
                    <div class="vc-image "><img alt="pegasus samos rent-a-car Opel Astra Elegance" src="/images/vehicles/opel_astra.jpg"></div>
                    <div class="vc-make-model">Opel Astra Elegance</div>
                    <div class="vc-engine">1400cc</div>
                    <div class="vc-features"><ul class="tabs list-inline"><li class="label label-info">5 Doors</li><li class="label label-info"> 5 Seats</li><li class="label label-info"> Air Con</li><li class="label label-info"> Automatic</li></ul></div>
                <a data-vehicle="15" class="btn btn-warning selected" href="#tab-booking">I'll have this one</a>
                 </div>
           </div>
                        <div class="v-details col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 vehicle5">
                <div>
                    <div class="vc-image "><img alt="pegasus samos rent-a-car Peugot 307 Cabrio" src="/images/vehicles/peugeot307.jpg"></div>
                    <div class="vc-make-model">Peugot 307 Cabrio</div>
                    <div class="vc-engine">1600cc</div>
                    <div class="vc-features"><ul class="tabs list-inline"><li class="label label-info">2 Doors</li><li class="label label-info"> 4 Seats</li><li class="label label-info"> Cabriolet</li><li class="label label-info"> Air Con</li></ul></div>
                <a data-vehicle="5" class="btn btn-warning selected" href="#tab-booking">I'll have this one</a>
                 </div>
           </div>
                        <div class="v-details col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 vehicle11">
                <div>
                    <div class="vc-image "><img alt="pegasus samos rent-a-car Suzuki Jimny" src="/images/vehicles/jimny.jpg"></div>
                    <div class="vc-make-model">Suzuki Jimny</div>
                    <div class="vc-engine">1300cc</div>
                    <div class="vc-features"><ul class="tabs list-inline"><li class="label label-info">2 Doors</li><li class="label label-info"> 4 Seats</li><li class="label label-info"> Cabriolet</li><li class="label label-info"> Air Con</li></ul></div>
                <a data-vehicle="11" class="btn btn-warning selected" href="#tab-booking">I'll have this one</a>
                 </div>
           </div>
                        <div class="v-details col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 vehicle14">
                <div>
                    <div class="vc-image "><img alt="pegasus samos rent-a-car Nissan Serena" src="/images/vehicles/serena.jpg"></div>
                    <div class="vc-make-model">Nissan Serena</div>
                    <div class="vc-engine">1600cc</div>
                    <div class="vc-features"><ul class="tabs list-inline"><li class="label label-info">5 Doors</li><li class="label label-info"> Air Con</li><li class="label label-info"> 8 Seats</li></ul></div>
                <a data-vehicle="14" class="btn btn-warning selected" href="#tab-booking">I'll have this one</a>
                 </div>
           </div>
                        <div class="v-details col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 vehicle13">
                <div>
                    <div class="vc-image "><img alt="pegasus samos rent-a-car Renault Espace" src="/images/vehicles/espace.jpg"></div>
                    <div class="vc-make-model">Renault Espace</div>
                    <div class="vc-engine">1900cc</div>
                    <div class="vc-features"><ul class="tabs list-inline"><li class="label label-info">4 Doors</li><li class="label label-info"> Air Con</li><li class="label label-info"> 7 Seats</li><li class="label label-info"> Diesel</li></ul></div>
                <a data-vehicle="13" class="btn btn-warning selected" href="#tab-booking">I'll have this one</a>
                 </div>
           </div>
                        <div class="v-details col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 vehicle3">
                <div>
                    <div class="vc-image "><img alt="pegasus samos rent-a-car Sym SR" src="/images/vehicles/sym150.jpg"></div>
                    <div class="vc-make-model">Sym SR</div>
                    <div class="vc-engine">150cc</div>
                    <div class="vc-features"></div>
                <a data-vehicle="3" class="btn btn-warning selected" href="#tab-booking">I'll have this one</a>
                 </div>
           </div>
                        <div class="v-details col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 vehicle2">
                <div>
                    <div class="vc-image "><img alt="pegasus samos rent-a-car Honda Transalp" src="/images/vehicles/honda_transalp_650cc.jpg"></div>
                    <div class="vc-make-model">Honda Transalp</div>
                    <div class="vc-engine">650cc</div>
                    <div class="vc-features"></div>
                <a data-vehicle="2" class="btn btn-warning selected" href="#tab-booking">I'll have this one</a>
                 </div>
           </div>
                        <div class="v-details col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 vehicle16">
                <div>
                    <div class="vc-image "><img alt="pegasus samos rent-a-car Honda XR" src="/images/vehicles/honda-xr-125.jpg"></div>
                    <div class="vc-make-model">Honda XR</div>
                    <div class="vc-engine">125cc</div>
                    <div class="vc-features"></div>
                <a data-vehicle="16" class="btn btn-warning selected" href="#tab-booking">I'll have this one</a>
                 </div>
           </div>


        </fieldset>
```

It's on my development machine so I can't give you a link.  the results look like this
[flexbox issue with safari](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2Eu6.jpg)

Comment: use display:flex; in the parent and it will give equal heights to all the children..

Comment: I'm impressed!  I've seen flex flying around here and there but never used it or researched it.  After an initial display problem of layout being broken, I discovered that I need to add flex-wrap:wrap as well. `style="display:flex; flex-wrap:wrap;"`

Comment: it is the simplest and most flexible grid system that I have worked with and it does not add additional markup and solves complex problems with a few lines of simple and understandable code..use Flexbox and make your life easy..

Comment: I have a problem with @DhavalChheda s suggestion! Flexbox is working fine on firefox (pc/mac) but on safari (mac & iphone/ipad) I just get a single column of div's it seems to be breaking the col-md-4 col-sm-6

Comment: adding `style="display: -webkit-flex; display: flex; -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap; flex-wrap: wrap;"` did not fix the problem, I'm still getting a single column of divs on safari

Comment: show the code that you have and explain the problem that you have with the code..

Comment: Found the problem
it looks like firefox is okay with me applying flexbox to the fieldset however safari is not.  Adding a container div inside the fieldset and applying the flexbox to that has fixed the problem for safari.  Thanks @DhavalChheda for suggesting flexbox. :-)

Answer (score 0):

> Found the problem. It looks like Firefox is okay with me applying `flexbox` to the `fieldset`, however, Safari is not.
>
> Adding a container `div` inside the `fieldset` and applying the `flexbox` to that has fixed the problem for Safari.
>
> Thanks [@DhavalChheda](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5538504/dhaval-chheda) for suggesting `flexbox`. :-)

by [philip](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5980373/philip)